# Imagemagick LNK2019 Error While Building

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, imagemagick, windows-7-x64, lnk2019

I am trying to build a project that uses Imagemagick library. I have done the following:

- Added Libraries in VC++ Directories in Tools -> Options
- Added "C:\ImageMagick-6.8.6-Q16\include\Magick++";"C:\ImageMagick-6.8.6-Q16" in Project Properties -> Configuration -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Libraries
- Added "C:\ImageMagick-6.8.6-Q16\lib";"C:\ImageMagick-6.8.6-Q16"  in Project Properties -> Configuration -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories
- Added CORE_RL_magick_.lib CORE_RL_Magick++_.lib CORE_RL_wand_.lib X11.lib in Project Properties -> Configuration -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependancies
- Added C:\ImageMagick-6.8.6-Q16  in Environment Variables PATH

However, when building the project, I get several LNK2019 errors, the first is:

```
Error 28 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall Magick::Image::~Image(void)" (__imp_??1Image@Magick@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "class Imagen & __cdecl lee(char *,int)" (?lee@@YAAAVImagen@@PADH@Z)   inout.obj
```

Comment: With which tool are you building? Can you print the command line that fails? It's likely that you are actually missing either a flag -l ([link to library](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html)) or -L (directories where to find the library, this is less likely as you would get a different error)

Comment: @Antonio I'm building the project on Visual Studio 2005. I'm not sure what you mean by command line. As for linking the libraries, I thought the steps I have done previously (mentioned above) were for that aim.